# Generate a list of equations of curves and plot them

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I want to plot a series of lines. This is how I did it:

```
Table[{y==(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i,y==-(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i,x==i*Sqrt[3]/2,x==i*Sqrt[3]/2},{i, -3, 3}]

(*Output: 
{{y == -3 + x/Sqrt[3], y == -3 - x/Sqrt[3]}, {y == -2 + x/Sqrt[3], 
y == -2 - x/Sqrt[3]}, {y == -1 + x/Sqrt[3], 
y == -1 - x/Sqrt[3]}, {y == x/Sqrt[3], 
y == -(x/Sqrt[3])}, {y == 1 + x/Sqrt[3], 
y == 1 - x/Sqrt[3]}, {y == 2 + x/Sqrt[3], 
y == 2 - x/Sqrt[3]}, {y == 3 + x/Sqrt[3], y == 3 - x/Sqrt[3]}} *)




 ContourPlot[{
    {y == -3 + x/Sqrt[3], y == -3 - x/Sqrt[3], x == -((3 Sqrt[3])/2)}, 
    {y == -2 + x/Sqrt[3], y == -2 - x/Sqrt[3], x == -Sqrt[3]},
    {y == -1 + x/Sqrt[3], y == -1 - x/Sqrt[3], x == -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, 
    {y == x/Sqrt[3], y == -(x/Sqrt[3]), x == 0}, 
    {y == 1 + x/Sqrt[3], y == 1 - x/Sqrt[3], x == Sqrt[3]/2}, 
    {y == 2 + x/Sqrt[3], y == 2 - x/Sqrt[3], x == Sqrt[3]}, 
    {y == 3 + x/Sqrt[3], y == 3 - x/Sqrt[3], x == (3 Sqrt[3])/2}}, 
    {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
  ]
```

This works.
[image: Triangle Lattice]

But it is kind of stupid and tedious. I hope to do it more concisely.

Then I tried in these ways:

```
eqns = Table[{y==(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i,y == -(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i}, {i, -3, 3}];
ContourPlot[eqns, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

or straightforwardly:

```
ContourPlot[
  Table[{y==(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i,y==-(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i}, {i, -3, 3}],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
]
```

or, using pure functions perhaps?

```
eqns[#1,#2]&=Table[{#2 == (1/Sqrt[3])*#1 + i, #2 == -(1/Sqrt[3])*#1 + i, #1 == 
i*Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, -7, 7}] &
ContourPlot[eqns[#1,#2]&[x,y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

But these didn't work.

So how to achieve this in a more concise way? Are there any possible methods using pure functions, mapping, and all kinds of these things to get it done? (I am a beginner in *Mathematica*, not quite familiar with the functions or these kind of things and I am still learning about it. )

If there are any other resources that could help me figure it out, please tell me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, and 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Comment: Why not just `Plot[]`? `Plot[Table[{i + x/Sqrt[3], i - x/Sqrt[3]}, {i, -3, 3}] // Flatten // Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}]`

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  Perhaps, you meant `Plot[Evaluate[
Table[{(1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, -(1/Sqrt[3])*x + i}, {i, -7, 7}]], {x, -3,  3}]`.  No `Flatten` or `y`.

Comment: Ah, @bbgodfrey, forgot to remove the other iterator; thanks. But the result is still a nested list; okay if OP wants the pairs to have the same color, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
eqns = Table[{y==(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i,y == -(1/Sqrt[3])*x+i}, {i, -3, 3}];

ContourPlot[Evaluate[## & @@@ eqns], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eqns2 = Table[{ x == i Sqrt[3]/2, y == (1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, 
                y == -(1/Sqrt[3])*x + i}, {i, -7, 7}];

ContourPlot[Evaluate[## & @@@ eqns2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank u very much! This is quite concise.

Comment: @atoman, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 7):

You need to either join all desired plots, e.g.

```
ContourPlot[#, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red] &@(Join @@ 
   Table[{y == (1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, y == -(1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, 
     x == i*Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, -7, 7}])
```

or `Show`, e.g.:

```
Show[ContourPlot[#, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    ContourStyle -> Red] & /@ 
  Table[{y == (1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, y == -(1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, 
    x == i*Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, -7, 7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: …although, it might be simpler to use `Line[]` or the newer `InfiniteLine[]` to generate the required picture.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I guess I was not so much interested in the underlying aim but addressing achieving it...agree other ways to achieve this result :-)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Hmm... `Graphics[GeometricTransformation[InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {0, 1}], Flatten@Outer[Dot,Table[RotationTransform[2 Pi/3 i], {i, 3}], Table[TranslationTransform[{i Sqrt[3]/2, 0}], {i, -Ceiling[3/(Sqrt[3]/2)], Ceiling[3/(Sqrt[3]/2)]}]]], PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> True]` --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/2XcZx.png suggests $\infty\approx\sqrt{2}$.  (`Line[]` works fine.)

Comment: @Michael, wow. Now that's something to report…

Answer (score 5):

```
eqs = Table[{y == (1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, y == -(1/Sqrt[3])*x + i, x == i*Sqrt[3]/2},
    {i, -7, 7}];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x, y} /. ToRules /@ Flatten[eqs] /. {x -> t, y -> t}],
 {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: neat use of ToRules +1 :)

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks. +1, to you, too.

Comment: Thank u very much! By this I begin to learn the ToRules.